# Spark driver pod eviction Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

What would be the recommended approach to wait for spark driver pod to complete the currently running job before it gets evicted to new nodes while maintenance on the current node is goingon (kernel upgrade,hardware maintenance etc..) using drain command

I don’t think I can use PoDisruptionBudget as Spark pods deployment yaml(s) is taken by Kubernetes